# Can we use Python modules with Apache Cordova?

Tags: python, cordova

I've been building an application using Apache Cordova - it's actually based on machine learning, but all my machine learning prototyping has been done in Python.

**Is there a way I could incorporate my Python libraries (like `scikit-learn`) into my Apache Cordova app**, or is there something else I should include?

*Thank you, any help would be appreciated!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't embed a programming language as a plugin for Cordova. You can however do a remote call to a server running python.

Comment: Thank you so much - do you have any links / tutorials which I can follow along to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking how to do an AJAX call to a server?

Comment: Yes - how could I run a Python script on a server and receive the data via AJAX?

Comment: That's rather a broad question, way too big to be answered even on SO.